# Let $X$ be a PDE. If we apply the method of characteristics to $X\cdot y_1$(x)$=1$, why do we get $\frac{dx_1}{...}=\frac{dx_2}{...}=\frac{dy_1}{1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Being more specific I'm talking about that X:

$X=x_1\:\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}\:+\:2x_{2\:}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2}$

If we apply the method of characteristics to $X\cdot y_1=1$, we get $\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{2x_2}=\frac{dy_1}{1}$

Why? Our PDE is

$x_1\:\frac{\partial \:y_1}{\partial \:x_1}\:+\:2x_{2\:}\frac{\partial y_1\:}{\partial \:x_2}=y_1$

Shouldn't we then get:

$\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{2x_2}=\frac{dy_1}{y_1}$

Comment: Your question is confusing. If the PDE is $$x_{1} \partial_{x_{1}} y + 2x_{2} \partial_{x_{2}} y = \color{red}{y}$$ then $$\frac{dx_{1}}{x_{1}} = \frac{dx_{2}}{2x_{2}} = \frac{dy}{\color{red}{y}}$$ If the PDE is $$x_{1} \partial_{x_{1}} y + 2x_{2} \partial_{x_{2}} y = \color{red}{1}$$ then $$\frac{dx_{1}}{x_{1}} = \frac{dx_{2}}{2x_{2}} = \frac{dy}{\color{red}{1}}$$

Comment: I also recognized this tbh, I somehow thought that you multiply it both sides. Question can be closed, I invite you to my other question about PDEs I've posted earlier this day but no one saw it